# Should I change env vars to use the node script under msys git bash in Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, msysgit, msys2, isparta

Should I change the env vars to be able to use my npm script under msys git bash in Windows?

I have the following test script:

```
console.log("Test nodejs by using msys git bash");

var fs = require('fs');
console.log('__dirname', __dirname);
console.log("typeof fs", typeof fs);

var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello Node.js\n');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');

var isparta = require('isparta');
console.log("typeof isparta", typeof isparta);
```

While attempting to run this script, I am receiving the error below:

```
module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module 'isparta'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\wamp\www\test.js:15:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
```

isparta was installed as global module:

```
npm install -g isparta@3.1.0
```

It can be found with 'which' an 'where'.

isparta from msysgit terminal:

```
$ which isparta
/c/ProgramData/npm/isparta
```

isparta from Windows cmd:

```
$ where isparta
c:\ProgramData\npm\isparta
c:\ProgramData\npm\isparta.cmd
```